# Get occurrences of a string in a list of strings.

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 textboxes and a button, when the button is clicked I want it to take a list I have created and have put into lower case and check the amount of occurrences each string appears.

My code:

```
Private Sub FlatButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim userString As String = userInput.Text
    userString = userString.ToLower()
    Dim inputList As New List(Of String)(userString.Split(" "))

    While count <= inputList.Count - 1
        output.Text &= inputList(count) & " Occurred: " & NEED TO GET OCCURRENCE & Environment.NewLine
        count = count + 1
    End While
End Sub
```

What would be the best way to keep a count for each and every word?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple LINQ expression:

```
Dim userString As String = "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood"

Dim userStringGroupByWords = userString.Split(" ").GroupBy(Function(word) word)

For Each word In userStringGroupByWords
    Console.WriteLine($"Word: {word.Key}, Count: {word.Count}")
   'Or Console.WriteLine("Word: {0}, Count: {1}", word.Key, word.Count)
   'if you are not using VS 2015 and .NET >= 4.6
Next
```

Output:

```
Group: How, Count: 1
Group: much, Count: 1
Group: wood, Count: 2
Group: would, Count: 1
Group: a, Count: 2
Group: woodchuck, Count: 2
Group: chuck, Count: 2
Group: if, Count: 1
Group: could, Count: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Dictionary to store the words and their counts:

```
Option Infer On
' ....
Dim s = "The only cat sat only on the cat mat"
Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

Dim ws = s.ToLower().Split(" "c)

For Each w In ws
    If d.ContainsKey(w) Then
        d(w) += 1
    Else
        d.Add(w, 1)
    End If
Next

For Each de In d
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10}{1,2}", de.Key, de.Value))
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

Outputs:

```
the        2
only       2
cat        2
sat        1
on         1
mat        1
```

(The descending counts are only coincidence.)

Comment: What would be the best way to append that to a textbox? http://pastebin.com/vXmZk9a9

Comment: @MeeMeme Use `output.AppendText(String.Format("{0,-10}{1,2}" & VbCrLf, de.Key, de.Value))` instead of the `Console.WriteLine(...)` line.

Comment: @MeeMeme Please see my comment of Sep 21 at 9:49.

Comment: I now have this outputted: http://s10.postimg.org/4mzj1vyt5/Capture.png

Comment: @MeeMeme Sorry, I was under the impression that `output` was a some control which would have `.AppendText`. Try `output.Text &= String.Format("{0,-10}{1,2}" & VbCrLf, de.Key, de.Value)`. You really should have looked at what was going on and tried something yourself ;)